# Discontinuous borders in tables from Tabularx

Tags: tabularx

I am new to LATEX and this forum. I was trying to make a table using the tabularX package (the only allowed one for the journal submission). I get the table right but the borders appear disjointed because of the merged cells. I would very much appreciate if anyone could/would help me through this.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Summary table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|X|c|}  
    \hline
        Region & Variables & \multicolumn{1}{p{7em}|}{XX} & \multicolumn{1}{p{8em}|}{XXXXXXX} & \multicolumn{1}{p{7em}|}{XXXXXXS} & XX  & XX   & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.13em}|}{XX} \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        \multirow{4}[8]{*}{AA} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{TT} & Overall & 0.99  & 0.99  & 1.13  & 0.971 & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{365} \bigstrut\\
        \cline{3-7}      &       & Season & 0.978 & 0.977 & 1.288 & 0.936 &  \bigstrut\\
        
        \cline{2-8}      & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{PP} & Overall & 0.933 & 0.83  & 2.637 & 0.856 & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{449} \bigstrut\\
        \cline{3-7}      &       & Season & 0.95  & 0.823 & 2.166 & 0.883 &  \bigstrut\\
       
    \end{tabularx}%
    \hline
    \label{tab:krig_sum}
    }
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please extend this to a full but minimal example that other can copy and try without having to add anything.

Comment: What exactly is that `}` on a single line suppose to do? What is `\bigstrut`?

Comment: Unrelated: note that you should place `\label` right after `\caption` just in case you have any data it also might attach it self onto.

Comment: The reason is that the overall width of you table is larger than  \textwidth, and it overflows into the margin, but the `\hline` s, in a tabularx, will be \textwidth long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you `X` column type not just to the penultimate column but to all columns from 4 to 7. I would further like to suggest that you give the table a much more open and inviting "look", by omitting all vertical rules and well-spaced horizontal rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, and \cmidrule macros
\usepackage{multirow} % for \multirow macro
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X} % centered version of 'X' col. type
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Summary table\strut} \label{tab:krig_sum}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lll *{4}{S[table-format=1.3]} c @{}}  
    \toprule
    Region & Variables & XX & 
    \mC{XXXX XXX} & \mC{XXXX XXS} & \mC{XX} & \mC{XX} & XX \\
    \midrule
     \multirow{5.2}{*}{AA} 
        & \multirow{2.3}{*}{TT} & Overall & 0.99  & 0.99  & 1.13  & 0.971 & \multirow{2.3}{*}{365} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){3-7}      
        &       & Season & 0.978 & 0.977 & 1.288 & 0.936 &  \\    
     \cmidrule(l){2-8}      
        & \multirow{2.3}{*}{PP} & Overall & 0.933 & 0.83  & 2.637 & 0.856 & \multirow{2.3}{*}{449} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){3-7}     
        &       & Season & 0.95  & 0.823 & 2.166 & 0.883 &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```